# Are there no way to know a ftp shell script failed?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have an experience of using shell script to ftp some file. And some files could just missed. For example for I have 100000 files to be ftp, there might be 1 or 2 files haven't been ftp and there is no obvious error.

The shell didn't stop when one of the files failed to be ftp, although we don't want the script to stop due to only 1 missing file, we still want it to have some feedback to know there is a problem.

Would it be better if we use java to ftp?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use ftp at all -- but rather consider something like rsync which can restart failed transfers and only transfer the files which has been updated since last.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are asking if java is better makes me think you are more proficient in java.  It's probably best to use whatever language you are more comfortable with.

Unless it's perl ;) j/k